# 4x4 workspace in Gnome Shell

Tags: gnome, workspaces, gnome-shell-extension

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to get 2x2 workspaces in Gnome 3.x?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116801/is-there-a-way-to-get-2x2-workspaces-in-gnome-3-x)

The compiz plugin for workspaces allows you to define the grid size to use for work spaces. In Gnome shell it seems that you are limited to one column that always keeps one extra workspace empty.

Is there anyway to configure gnome shell to use a 4x4 grid (with or without the auto extending, I don't care about that)?