# Is there a way to get 2x3 workspaces in gnome 3.6

Tags: gnome, workspaces

All the extensions and workarounds I can find don't seem to work in gnome 3.6.  Is there any way to get this to work in gnome 3.6?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get a workspace grid in Gnome 3.x?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/116801/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-workspace-grid-in-gnome-3-x)

Answer (score 0):

Check this extension (works with GS 3.6 and 3.8 as well): https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/484/workspace-grid/