# Workspace Grid 2x2

Tags: 17.10, workspaces, gnome-shell

I switched from Ubuntu 16.04 to 17.10.

Then, I found out that Workspace Grid can mimic my previous Unity 2x2 Workspace.

But there is a problem that is annoying me and I was not able to solve so far.

I start with two workspaces. To get a third one, I **must** have some software opened on the other two workspaces. And so on.

What I need is that my four workspaces will be always there, despite there is something opened or not.

Is there a way to this with Workspace Grid or some other extersion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to get a workspace grid in Gnome 3.x?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116801/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-workspace-grid-in-gnome-3-x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First install *(GNOME) Tweaks* by running

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Then launch *Tweaks* and go to the "*Workspaces*" section. Select "Static Workspaces" instead of "*Dynamic Workspaces*" and set the "*Number of Workspaces*" to **4**.

[image]