# I miss Unity workspaces. How to have them in Gnome?

Tags: unity, workspaces, gnome-shell

I switched from Unity to Gnome in 18.04 and I really miss how workspaces worked in Unity. A simple button displayed all workspaces and you could drag and drop windows to any. You could also drag one window to left, right, or top, and would move to another workspace almost like the monitor was extended into 4 pieces. You could also right click the top bar of any window and choose to move that window to any workspace. On top of that you could set up any window to appear on all workspaces or only on one.

All in all you had awesome options to make the workflow perfect. I miss that. Is there anything remotely for Gnome in this regards?

Comment: You can disable "dynamic" workspaces and [set no. of workspaces to 4](https://askubuntu.com/q/1026229). You can have [2x2 workspaces instead of a single column layout](https://askubuntu.com/q/966442). You can right click the top bar and enable/disable  "always on visible workspace" and "move to workspace down/up" etc. Also you can still use Unity.

Comment: Thanks. But I tried all of what you suggested before. It is nothing like the old Unity where I only clicked a Dash (favorites) button and have all workspaces spread (like the screen divided  into 4) and I could easily drag and drop (move) any window from any workspace. Simple and super efficient. In Gnome I get a popup bar with workspaces that I don't even know how to activate, and it is uncomfortable the way it works tbh. At least is there a way to make this popup full screen to see all screens big on the screen and move windows between them?

Comment: And I managed to figure out the right click on window top and move to another workspace or always visible on workspaces - had to go to Gnome Tweaks and enable that. So that's a plus. But I miss the simple button that divided the screen into 4 workspaces and allowed for drag and drop between these workspaces. Gnome basically adds a popup with workspaces that are small and not intuitive I'll say in terms of moving windows between them.

Comment: I'm not really aware of that great feature in GNOME. You'd be better off using Unity instead.

Comment: Yeah I tried to still use Unity but I lack other features from Gnome and overall I like Gnome more. But I may get used to Gnome Workspaces though I am still trying to find something on par with the Unity workspaces - that was so flawless and intuitive.

Comment: In that case try getting used to keyboard shortcuts, <ctrl><shift><alt>arrows to move the focussed window to another workspace and so on.

Comment: Thanks. That's a bit cumbersome but will see...