# How do I get grid workspaces in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: workspaces

I know that I have to use some tweaking tool and then a extension for this.
But all extensions that are suggested for this(Workspace grid, Workspace matrix), aren't available in the software center.

Comment: https://extensions.gnome.org/ did not you check in this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/TroSg.png

Comment: Yeah, I've seen this. But how I install an extension from there? I just get a zip with no readme, and the tweaking tool(Tweaks) doesn't have any way to select some downloaded extension and install it.

Comment: Ah, it appears I needed to install chrome-gnome-shell. Also when I use it in firefox. Then there appears some install button on the extensions page

Comment: See also this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/116801/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-workspace-grid-in-gnome-3-x

Answer (score 12):

I use [Workspace Matrix Gnome Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1485/workspace-matrix/) and it works just perfectly and has some useful configuration settings.

[image: workspace matrix]

Comment: Moving windows through the workspaces doesn't work. Any workarounds?

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+Shift+direction keys will let you move the window to different workspaces

Comment: Workspace Matrix Gnome Extension is not in ubuntu store.
People need someone to do 'sudo apt install xxx'

Answer (score 6):

On Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS and Gnome 3.36.8, Firefox 90.0, follow these steps to enable it:

1. Navigate to https://extensions.gnome.org/ (tested with Firefox and Chrome)
2. Click "Click here to install browser extension" (e.g., in Chrome it's [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gnome-shell-integration/gphhapmejobijbbhgpjhcjognlahblep/related) plugin)

   > [image: Install extension]
3. Search "Workspace Matrix" and enter its detail page

   > [image: Search]
4. Turn on the extension by click top-right button

   > [image: Turn on extension]
5. Navigate to extension settings by click to-right button of step 4, or search "extension" in the activities window, or click on "installed extensions" on top

   > [image: Settings]

Final effect:

[image: Final effect]

That's all.