# enable matrix workspace on Ubuntu 20.04 without relying on 'untrusted' code or extensions

Tags: 20.04, workspaces

I run Ubuntu 20.04. I would like to have a matrix of desktops (ie 2x2 desktops instead of desktops only in the vertical direction).

How to / is there a way to do this WITHOUT the need to enable some untrusted gnome extensions?

For example, by contrast: when I wanted to auto-hide the top bar, I could install gnome-tweaks (this is well an official package, so trusted, right?) and then run `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-autohidetopbar` (also trusted, right?). I suppose this means that all the code used is 'trusted', as everything happened through the official ubuntu software repository and some `sudo apt install`, right? Or am I missing something?

By contrast, the tutorials I find to get a workspace matrix either rely on finding `Workspace Matrix` in the ubuntu software (which I cannot find searching for it), or on enabling some gnome extensions that are not trusted at one or another point in time.

I am quite confused and may probably be missing something. Anybody who can enlighten me on that?

Comment: see the about page on GNOME-Shell extensions: https://extensions.gnome.org/about/

Comment: What do you mean by these two words? "Trusted" and "untrusted" By whom? Just because you can install something by `apt` doesn't make it "trusted" automatically and vice versa.

Comment: Well, from my understanding there is a level of trust associated with packages that can be installed through apt from official ubuntu repositories, right? This is what I mean: there is probably more trust to have in an official Ubuntu package available through apt, than through something installed with a custom PPA, or a gnome script with little known / transparent author, isn't it? :)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the details about gnome shell, good to see these are reviewed. Still, I would expect 'core' Ubuntu packages are even better checked, right? Or am I wrong?

Comment: So to User: this partly answers. I would prefer to have something that is directly from apt get similar to the autohide as I would expect this would mean that it has gone through more scrutiny. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Ok, after checking the Gnome extensions site in more details it does seem this is as safe as anything else. Then I agree that the solution pointed to is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gnome extensions are supposed to be reviewed and as trusted as anything else, in which case the solution becomes similar to what is provided in:

[How do I get grid workspaces in ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232919/how-do-i-get-grid-workspaces-in-ubuntu-20-04)

The way I personally installed it was to go with my browser (firefox, but should be similar with other browsers) to:

https://extensions.gnome.org/local/

There allow extension plugin management installation, and then browse for `Workspace Matrix` extension as recommended on the other issue.